# Fetch Images From SharePoint Into Bootstrap Modal/Carousel

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint

I'm fetching images from SharePoint REST API and writing the calls along with HTML into an HTML doc.

Specifically a Bootstrap Modal Carousel.

I'm getting all the images and content writing to some tiles. The problem are the images in the Modal.

The user clicks on an icon, the Modal fires, the first image in the Carousel displays but it won't navigate next/previous, even though the HTML is being written for each one.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container"> 

        <!-- GLOBAL NAVIGATION -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/nav.js"></script>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /end global nav -->



        <!-- TILE WRAPPER -->
        <div class="row bgTexture bgTexture2 ">
            <div class="col-md-12">

        <!-- TOP ROW OF TILES -->
        <div class="row aoTilesTopWrapper">
            <h2>TITLE GOES HERE</h2>  


            <!-- ///////// BOOTSTRAP ROTATOR -->
            <div class=" col-md-12 allModals">








            </div><!-- /end allModals -->









            </div>
            <!-- ///////// end bootstrap modal -->
        </div><!-- /end row - top row  -->


        <!-- BOTTOM ROW OF TILES -->
        <div class="row aoTilesBottomWrapper">

            <!-- BOTTOM ROW TILES GO HERE -->


        </div><!-- /end row - bottom row  -->
            </div><!-- /end col-md-12 -->




            </div><!-- /end main row -->

        </div><!-- /end container /content -->


    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/js/custom.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/js/add-ons.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>    
    // Select third list item
    var liToSelect = 7;
    $(".nav.nav-pills li:eq("+(liToSelect-1)+")").addClass("active");


    $(document).ready(function(){
        addOns();

    });

    $('.carousel').carousel({
        pause: true,
        interval: false
    });



    </script>
```

JS/Ajax:

```
function addOns(){
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "/_api/lists/getByTitle('Products')/items",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose", "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {  
            $.each(data.d.results, function () {
                var itemID = this.Id;
                // Image tiles
                var aoTiles = "<div class='col-sm-4 tile' data-imageID='" + this.Id + "'><span class='openRotator' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.itemID" + this.Id + "'><a href='#'><img src='/media/new-window-icon.png' width='20'/></a></span><div class='tileImg'><img src='" + this.Tile_x0020_Thumbnail_.Url + "'/></div><div class='tileTitle'>" + this.Title + "</div><div class='tilePrice'>" + this.Content_x0020_Starting_x.toFixed(2) + "</div></div>";
                $(".aoTilesTopWrapper").append(aoTiles);

                // Modal
                $(".allModals").append("<div class='modal fade bs-example-modal-lg itemID" + this.Id + "' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myLargeModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'><div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'><div class='modal-content'><div id='carouselId" + this.ID + "' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'><!-- Wrapper for slides --><div id='carousel' class='carousel-inner'><!-- Gallery images go here --></div><!-- Controls --><a class='left carousel-control' href='#carouselId" + this.Id + "' role='button' data-slide='prev'></a> <a class='right carousel-control' href='#carouselId" + this.Id + "' role='button' data-slide='next'></a></div></div></div></div>");

                // Carousel divs002
                $.each(this.Carousel_x0020_Image_x002.split(";"), function () {
                    $(".modal.itemID"+ itemID +" .carousel-inner").append("<div class='item'><img src='" + this + "'/></div>");
                });


            });


        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.statusText);
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

Any idea why the carousel images aren't sliding?

Comment: have you tried moving the whole $('.carousel').carousel function inside the addOns success function... after all DOM elements are created

Answer (score 0):

You're going to laugh. The first `<div class="item">` needed the `.active` class in order for it to work.

Duh!